# Extracting data from XML / Text file using Perl software

Tags: xml, perl

I need your help to learn the xml/text format files extraction my xml/txt files contain's a huge data as below mentioned format.

```
<authorList>
<author>
<fullName>Oliver LA</fullName>
<firstName>L A</firstName>
<lastName>Oliver</lastName>
<initials>LA</initials>
<authorAffiliationDetailsList>
<authorAffiliation>
<affiliation>University of Liverpool, Liverpool, UK. Electronic address: l.oliver@liverpool.ac.uk.</affiliation>
</authorAffiliation>
</authorAffiliationDetailsList>
</author>
<author>
<fullName>Hutton DP</fullName>
<firstName>D P</firstName>
<lastName>Hutton</lastName>
<initials>DP</initials>
<authorAffiliationDetailsList>
<authorAffiliation>
<affiliation>North West Radiotherapy Operational Delivery Network, The Christie Hospital, Manchester, UK; University of Liverpool, Liverpool, UK.</affiliation>
</authorAffiliation>
</authorAffiliationDetailsList>
</author>
<author>
<fullName>Hall T</fullName>
<firstName>T</firstName>
<lastName>Hall</lastName>
<initials>T</initials>
<authorAffiliationDetailsList>
<authorAffiliation>
<affiliation>North West Radiotherapy Operational Delivery Network, The Christie Hospital, Manchester, UK.</affiliation>
</authorAffiliation>
</authorAffiliationDetailsList>
</author>
<author>
<fullName>Cain M</fullName>
<firstName>M</firstName>
<lastName>Cain</lastName>
<initials>M</initials>
<authorAffiliationDetailsList>
<authorAffiliation>
<affiliation>Clatterbridge Cancer Centre, Liverpool, UK.</affiliation>
</authorAffiliation>
</authorAffiliationDetailsList>
</author>
<author>
<fullName>Bates M</fullName>
<firstName>M</firstName>
<lastName>Bates</lastName>
<initials>M</initials>
<authorAffiliationDetailsList>
<authorAffiliation>
<affiliation>East of England Radiotherapy Network, Norfolk &amp; Norwich University Hospital, Norwich, UK.</affiliation>
</authorAffiliation>
</authorAffiliationDetailsList>
</author>
<author>
<fullName>Cree A</fullName>
<firstName>A</firstName>
<lastName>Cree</lastName>
<initials>A</initials>
<authorAffiliationDetailsList>
<authorAffiliation>
<affiliation>Clatterbridge Cancer Centre, Liverpool, UK.</affiliation>
</authorAffiliation>
</authorAffiliationDetailsList>
</author>
<author>
<fullName>Mullen E</fullName>
<firstName>E</firstName>
<lastName>Mullen</lastName>
<initials>E</initials>
<authorAffiliationDetailsList>
<authorAffiliation>
<affiliation>Clatterbridge Cancer Centre, Liverpool, UK.</affiliation>
</authorAffiliation>
</authorAffiliationDetailsList>
</author>
</authorList>
```

I need the output format like Email,firstName,lastname,affiliation and the output should be exported to a text file.

By using Perl software, I have developed a code which is mentioned below.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open(FILEHANDLE, "<data.xml")|| die "Can't open";
my @line;
my @affi;

my @lines;
my $ct =1 ;
print "Enter the start position:-";

my $start= <STDIN>;
print "Enter the end position:-";


my $end = <STDIN>;

print "Processing your data...\n";
my $i =0;
my $t =0;
while(<FILEHANDLE>)
{
    if($ct>$end)
    {
       close(FILEHANDLE);
       exit;
       
    }
    if($ct>=$start)
    {
       $lines[$t] = $_;
       $t++;
     }
     
     if($ct == $end)
     {
    my $i = 0;
    my $j = 0;
    my @last;
    my @first;
    my $l = @lines;
    my $s = 0;

while($j<$l)
{
    if ($lines[$j] =~m/@/)
    {
        $line[$i] = $lines[$j];
        $s = $j-3;
        $first[$i]=$lines[$s]; 
        $s--;
        $last[$i] = $lines[$s];
        #$j = $j+3;
        #$last[$i]= $lines[$j];
        #$j++;
        #$first[$i] = $lines[$j];
        $i++;
    }
$j++;
}
my $k = 0;
foreach(@line)
{
  $line[$k] =~ s/<.*>(.* )(.*@.*)<.*>/$2/;
  $affi[$k] = $1;
  $line[$k] = $2;
    $line[$k] =~ s/\.$//;
    
    
    $k++;
  }

my $u = 0;
foreach(@first)
{
  $first[$u] =~s/<firstName>(.*)<.*>/$1/;
  $first[$u]=$l;  
  $u++
  }
my $m = 0;
foreach(@last)
{
  $last[$m] =~s/<lastName>(.*)<.*>/$1/;
  $last[$m] = $1;    
  $m++
  }
my $q=@line;
open(FILE,">RAVI.txt")|| die "can't open";
my $p;

for($p =0; $p<$q; $p++)
{  
  print FILE "$line[$p],$first[$p],$last[$p],$affi[$p]\n";
} 

close(FILE);
     }
     
  
  $ct++;
  }
```

By using this code I am able to get output
email, ,lastname,affiliation format.

I am not able to get the firstName by using the code from the given data. I am new to the Perl technology. I request you to please help me by fixing the mistakes in my code.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Better use https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath

Answer (score 4):

As I said in comment, better use a known `XML` parser. One of them is  [XML::XPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use XML::XPath;

my $file = shift or die $!;
my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => $file);

my $nodeset = $xp->find('/authorList//author');

foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
    my @contact;
    push @contact, $node->findvalue('./firstName');
    push @contact, $node->findvalue('./lastName');
    $_ = $node->findvalue('.//authorAffiliation/affiliation');
    push @contact, $& if m/\b\S+\@\S+/;
    say join ", ", @contact;
}
```

### Output

```
L A, Oliver, l.oliver@liverpool.ac.uk.
D P, Hutton
T, Hall
M, Cain
M, Bates
A, Cree
E, Mullen
```

### Usage

```
./XML::XPath.pl file.xml | tee new_file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer, Sir. And, the output should be like 

L A, Oliver, l.oliver@liverpool.ac.uk. format and the output should be saved to a .txt file 

Could you please help me by adding the few more lines to the code

Comment: Post edited accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was to try and write your own XML parser. That's a very hard thing to get right. Far better to use one that has already been written.

I always reach for [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML) (it has terrible documentation, but there's a [great tutorial online](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/)).

A first attempt at your program would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use XML::LibXML;

my $infile = shift
  or die "Usage: $0 xml_file\n";

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $infile);

my @nodes = qw[ firstName lastName
                authorAffiliationDetailsList/authorAffiliation/affiliation ];

for my $author ($dom->findnodes('//author')) {
  my @data = map { $author->findvalue($_) } @nodes;

  say join ',', map { qq["$_"] } @data;
}
```

Note that I've put all of your output into quotes - that's because the affiliation node contains embedded commas.

In reality, you'd need to process the affiliation data a little more to extract the email address. But I hope this gets you most of the way to a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer, Sir.

But the output should be like 

L A, Oliver, l.oliver@liverpool.ac.uk. format and the output should be saved to a .txt file 

Could you please help me by adding the few more lines to the code

Comment: @ravi.gteja: Honestly, not really. I've pointed you in the right direction and (to be honest) have done all the interesting work. I'm not interested in producing a complete solution for you. I've given you the framework and a pointer to a really good tutorial - the rest is up to you.

Comment: Can be shorter: https://hastebin.com/gacedebati.pl

Comment: @GillesQuenot: i suspect that's pretty much always true of Perl code :-)

Comment: TMTOWTDI........

Answer (score 0):

While I, too, would recommend using an XML parser and not using Regexes (unless you're that Damian!) we haven't told you what is wrong with your code.

Dump your data - using say Data::Dumper.

```
...
    $k++;
  }
use Data::Dumper;
warn Data::Dumper->new([\@line,\@first,\@last],[qw(*line *first *last)])->Deepcopy(1)->Indent(1)->Maxdepth(3)->Sortkeys(1)->Dump(),q{ };

my $u = 0;
foreach(@first)
{
...
```

And you will find that

```
@line = (
  '<affiliation>University of Liverpool, Liverpool, UK. Electronic address: l.oliver@liverpool.ac.uk.</affiliation>
'
);
@first = (
  '<initials>LA</initials>
'
);
@last = (
  '<lastName>Oliver</lastName>
'
);
```

@first isn't '<firstName>...</firstName>' but '<initials>LA</initials>' which is why your first name regexp never returns the expected value.